# Append char to jstring in C

Tags: c, file, java-native-interface

Currently I have that code:

```
const char *writeStringToFile = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, string, 0);
writeToFile(writeStringToFile);
(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, string, writeStringToFile);

void writeToFile(const char *string) {
FILE *f = fopen("Spieler.txt", "w");
if (f == NULL) {
    printf("Error opening file!\n");
    exit(1);
}

fprintf(f, string);
fclose(f);
}
```

I want to write that to my file but the `'\0'` is missing.
So is there a way to append the '\0' to the string?
It's not possible to strcat something to a const so what's the best way to solve it?

Comment: Can you not just copy the const string to a newly allocated string, that's a byte longer, that contains a `'\0'` a the end?

Comment: What the heck is a  jstring ?

Comment: I use `JNI` and jstring is parameter

Comment: I'm refusing to answer, since we don't know what writeToFile looks like.  Can you modify that code?  Can you make it take a parameter that says to include a null terminator?  If you can't, just call writeToFile(writeStringToFile); writeToFile('\0')?

Comment: I always have to write the '\0' in C?

Comment: Normally, one does not write the '\0' to the file.

Comment: Don't make a habit out of doing `fprintf(f, string);`, where `string` is given from outside. What if at some point `string` happens to contain conversion specifiers by accident (or not...). Use `fputs`.

Comment: Are you saying that `fprintf` writes more than it should because the string lacks a NUL terminator? Why are you `fprintf` at all? Why not just `fwrite` since you can query the string's length?